# sublime taking random input while running the program

Tags: c++, ide, sublimetext3

so i tried setting up sublime for programming today , like setting up the build system but when i try to run a normal program like the one shown in screenshot , the editor is giving me output without taking any input like it is supposed to do .
the code i used for build system

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++14", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UryTp.png)

i have tried reinstalling sublime and making the system build again but nothing seems to work , i want to know how i can fix this and make the program take input .
just for context this system build is for competitive programming

Comment: Did you try compiling this manually via g++ in command line?

Comment: You're redirecting the input with `<inputf.in`? Not sure what you're expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

this should run in a shell and to do so you can add cmd if you are using Windows

```
"cmd": ["cmd", "/C", "g++.exe", "-std=c++14", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
```